# System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file while parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jsch, stax

I have a method `processData()` which obtains the finished `filepath` before trying to send the file over `sftp` using `jsch` `put()`.

```
class Processer {

public void processData() {

                Path fileToSend = writer.buildFile(data, users, str);
                try {
                    sender.connect();
                    if (sender.send(fileToSend)) {
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Upload Failed");
                    }
                } catch (JSchException e) {
                   //log error
                } finally {
                    sender.dispose();
                }                   
    }

}

class WriterClass { 

   public Path buildFile(Map<String, List<Data>> data, Map<String, User> users) {

        XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamWriter writer = null;
        Path filePath = Paths.get(outputDir);
        Path fileDir = null;
        Path file = null;

        try {
            fileDir = Files.createDirectories(filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IO error {}", e);
        }

        try {

            file = Paths.get(fileDir.toString(), date + ".XML");
            writer = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter(file.toFile())));

            writer.writeStartDocument();
            writer.writeStartElement("OPEN");

            //for each entry in set 
            writeDetail(writer, data); //writes character data

            writer.writeEndElement(); 
            writer.writeEndDocument();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        }

        return file;
    }

}
```

When the file has been transferred across over sftp, the `xml` file is not complete on remote location and is not able to parse. It appears complete on the local path. Can anyone point out if I'm missing anything or the closing of  `writer` object or flushing is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason the full file was not being sent was because `count()` method for `SftpProgressMonitor` in jsch, was returning `false`. As the `count()` method gets periodically called it should be returning true to complete the transfer. [See Here](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html#count%28long%29)